# How to get previous date if the current date is a Holiday

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie to VB here and I got caught up in this situation.

I have a column which has dates in it.

```
A
1/31/2016
1/31/2016
1/31/2016
1/31/2016
```

Now in column B, I want to get the previous working date if the date mentioned in column A is a weekend or Holiday else the same date if the date mentioned in column A is a working day. So the output will be like.

```
A          B
1/31/2016  1/29/2016
1/31/2016  1/29/2016
1/31/2016  1/29/2016
1/31/2016  1/29/2016
```

I am currently using this code. But am getting error. Please let me know how to arrive at the desired output.

```
Sub Work_day()

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = wf.WorkDay(Range("A:A"), -1)
Next i

End Sub
```

The error am getting is "Unable to get the workday property of the worksheetfunction class"

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = wf.WorkDay(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A"), -1)` (Untested)

Comment: That worked perfect Siddharth.. Thank you so much

Comment: Just encountered a problem :( The query is returning the previous date for any date where as I want current date if it is a working day and previous date if it is a holiday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side will be able to capture only one value whereas the right hand side of the expression is trying to give out the result for the whole range of **A:A**

Small correction in the code gives the previous/current working day as returned by the function in Datevalue integer value:
    `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = wf.WorkDay(Range("A" & i), -1)`

This further can be converted into a date formatted value using the below formula in the excel cell.

`=TEXT(MONTH(B2)&"/"&DAY(B2)&"/"&YEAR(B2),"mm/dd/yyyy")`
 where range **B:B** is the result from the VB execution.

Comment: Just encountered a problem The query is returning the previous date for any date where as I want current date if it is a working day and previous date if it is a holiday. Not sure how to arrive at it.

Comment: Hope this works: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = wf.WorkDay(Range("A" & i)+1, -1)`

Comment: Good to know that it works!! Please accept the answer if it saves the day.. That would be a nice encouragement.

Comment: Hey @identifymecnu I tried to add the sheet containing Holidays just so to get previous day in case of Holiday.. I wrote the code something like this

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "CA").Value = wf.WorkDay((Range("E" & i) + 1), -1, Sheets("Holidays").Range("A1:A10"))

Now am getting the same "workday property of the worksheetfunction class" error.. Could you please let me know where am going wrong

Comment: I have the code `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B").Value = wf.WorkDay(Range("A" & i) + 1, -1, Sheets("Holidays").Range("A1:A2"))` which works.
As such, I tried with the line of code in your comment and that works as well!!